# Why is Sprout Forms returning 302 for ajax requests?

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutforms

I am using Sprout Forms on a Craft 3 site and trying to submit my form via ajax.

I've been able to do this many times in Craft 2, but not having much luck with 3 (yet). [The docs](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/submitting-a-form-via-ajax.html) look mainly for Craft 2 - is there a better way to find examples for Craft 3?

Here is what the headers look like that I am sending:

```
CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN: <huge string hash>
action: sprout-forms/entries/save-entry
redirect: <long redirect hash>
handle: contact
fields[fullName]: Damon
fields[email]: name@test.com
fields[phone]: 211-111-1111
fields[message]: Hello.
```

I am always getting a 302 response back - without any error or other indication of what might be missing. If I remove the `handle` field, I'll get a 400 error, so I know I'm hitting the correct method.

`Status Code: 302 Found`

Here is what my js looks like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    cache: false,
    data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
    url: $('input[name=action]').val(),
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 50000
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);  // nothing.
}).fail(function (error) {
    // Total fail.
});
```

Here is what I am including in my form that is Craft/Sprout specific.

```
{{ csrfInput() }}
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="sprout-forms/entries/save-entry">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ form.redirectUri|hash }}">
<input type="hidden" name="handle" value="{{ form.handle }}">
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to say thank you to the support staff at Sprout for helping me figure out my error.

I have the default install settings/configuration for a Sprout form. Spam protection was enabled in my case and that's what was causing the 302.

If I want to have spam protection enabled, I need to have this inside my `<form>` tags:

```
{% hook 'sproutForms.modifyForm' %}
```

So my form looks like this now:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" class="main-form" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <fieldset>
        {% hook 'sproutForms.modifyForm' %}
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sprout-forms/entries/save-entry">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ form.redirectUri|hash }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="{{ form.handle }}">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        {# Get the full name field. #}
        {% set fullName = form.getField('fullName') %}

        ...
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'm getting a 200 response back and the entry is getting created!